# How to set timestamp back to 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a MySQL table with a timestamp field

By default I can see that this field is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

I have some code that updates this field to a proper date. However I'd like to convert this field in some rows back to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

I tried something like: `UPDATE mytable SET myfield='0000-00-00 00:00:00' WHERE id=72;`

But that gives an error: `Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'myfield' at row 1`

How can I get around this?

Comment: whats the Data Type used for the filed

Answer (score 0):

If `myfield` column is of `datetime` datatype, you can use this to set the time to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = 0 WHERE id = 72;
```

Comment: Data type of this field is 'timestamp'. I tried your suggestion but got an error: MySQL said: Documentation
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0' for column 'myfield' at row 1

Comment: This might also be caused by strict SQL setting [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

Comment: Check your /etc/my.cnf file, set `sql-mode="TRADITIONAL"` and restart MySQL.